# How do I do a condition to XML code?

Tags: php, magento

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation"  
           name="cms_catalog" 
           template="catalog/catalog.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/product_new" 
           name="home.catalog.product.new" 
           alias="product_new" 
           template="catalog/product/newbar.phtml" />
    <block type="amreview/sidebar"    
           name="amreview_sidebar" 
           template="amreview/sidebar.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/product"
           template="catalog/product/specials.phtml" />
</reference>
```

I want to make a condition to decide when the use log in, then don't output `<block type="catalog/product"   template="catalog/product/specials.phtml" />` the block. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the specials block from within the customer_logged_in layout handle.

For example, you can modify your layout file like so:

```
<layout>
    ...
    <customer_logged_in>
        <remove name="specials" />
    </customer_logged_in>
</layout>
```

In the layout code that you posted, you'll need to add a name to your specials block and reference it in the remove node (I just used "specials" as an example).

There is also a customer_logged_out handle if you want to implement the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it from within "left" instead. In the appropriate `.phtml` file, you will probably find the line:

```
$this->getChildHtml();
```

which, without a parameter passed to it, will render each block in order.

You could replace that with:

```
$this->getChildHtml("cms_catalog");
$this->getChildHtml("home.catalog.product.new");
$this->getChildHtml("amreview_sidebar");
if ($condition) { // Find the approriate variable to define the condition.
    $this->getChildHtml("specials");
}
```